# BEGIN TRY above Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to have a `BEGIN / TRY` above the arameters of a procedure.

Like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_get_Reports_Parameter_Portfolio]
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS
DECLARE @ReportTable Table(
```

The reason I want this is because I raise a custom error via `RAISERROR`
whenever the try fails.

The reason I need to have the try ABOVE the insertion of the parameters is because I want my custom message to appear when a parameter that is input is the wrong type.

Comment: What type of application is feeding the stored procedure?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Currently its a reportviewer in c#, it does currently send the wrong type(i know why)...but i need my custom error message to show when it does send the wrong type.

Comment: This comes across as a convoluted solution to a problem that may have a simpler solution. I'm probably not understanding your situation. But...is the issue that your SP is getting called and an invalid date string is being passed in?

Comment: This should be handled in your c# app, prior to making the SQL Connection. Do you have a date picker in the Report Viewer?

Comment: @DMason the thing is, i know an invalid date is being passed, i have a Custom error message that i want to have raised when any exceptions happen, not just invalid parameters.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i cant, im using reportviewer to view the Reports that is on my SSRS server, any validation needs to be passed in SSDT or SQL exclusively.

Comment: If you pass in an incorrect string value for a `DATE` data type parameter, you get Msg 8114 `Error converting data type varchar to date.`. Why do you need a custom error message for that? It's pretty clear as it is.  Assuming correct date string values are passed to the SP, you can use BEGIN/TRY and return custom error messages from within the SP as you see fit. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DMason basically i want to return a exception message that says in which Stored Procedure the exception occurred...if you have a database with 300 Stored Procedures and the code starts becoming legacy code, it would be wonderful if it tells you were it broke.

Comment: The error message I see in SSMS shows the stored proc name. Here is an example:  `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.usp_Get_Reports_Parameter_Portfolio, Line 8
Error converting data type varchar to date.`  You aren't getting that in ReportViewer?

Comment: the only information the Reportviewer from winfroms gives you is the default error...so im raising an error that also says in which Stored procedure it broke.

Comment: @DMason Winforms Reportviewer only returns "Error converting data type varchar to date".....SSRS returns my custom message

Comment: Is there a way to validate report params in a BEGIN/TRY block *before* calling the SP?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

You must pass correct parameter types.
If you need to, you can check parameter values immediately inside the stored procedure:

```
IF DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), @StartDate) > 100
    ;THROW 50000, '@StartDate is invalid', 1
```

Also, you can wrap your stored procedure call in a `TRY` - `CATCH` block.

Comment: well thats kind of sad, would be so cool if they added the ability for you to move that try above the the parameter input.

Answer (score 1):

Any code within a stored procedure/function is reached **after** the stored procedure/function becomes **properly invoked**. As such, any exception handling mechanisms that you may wish to include within your stored procedure/function are not visible at the time of the invocation but only after such invocation was successful.

If the invocation takes place from a different system (e.g. a JAVA program), you should wrap the stored procedure/function invocation within the JAVA with the required TRY/CATCH pair.

If the invocation takes place from within the same database, the calling code should include the error handling piece.